# Managing Animator lifecycle from within custom view in custom list adapter

Tags: android, android-animation, android-custom-view

I have a custom view which automatically animates. It uses an `AnimatorSet` which calls `Animator.start()` in `onAnimationEnd()` in order to repeat endlessly. This is automatically started when the view is created.

These views are used in a `ListAdapter` (actually a `SackOfViewsAdapter` so there is no recycling going on). So it's important to manage when to cancel (or pause) the animation.

Maybe the animator should be registered with the adapter and then the `Activity` should call some method on that adapter to cancel any animations?

Another idea is to check, in `onAnimationEnd()` whether the `View` `isShowing()` (i.e. don't restart animation if not showing) but then this would cause issues when the `View` comes back into view.

This seems a little hacky to me, so I'm interested if there are better solutions.

Also, what happens if an animator is paused?  I guess it will not be garbage collected?

Comment: `View#onDetachedFromWindow` ?

Comment: This seems to solve the problem very well, thanks. I suppose it would make sense to start the animation in `onAttachedToWindow` to keep the symmetry and also handle situations where the view is reattached to a window. It's not perfect though, because the animations still need to be stopped/paused in `Activity.onPause` which means the animators still need to be tracked somehow. Oh, I guess `onWindowVisibilityChanged` would solve that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a simple `ListAdapter` you just have to start animation in `getView` of the adapter and drop everything else. When a new cell will come on screen it will be showing a freshly started animation and as the cells are being re-used there is no need to cancel animations on the cells which go out of the screen.

Comment: Thanks and yes that is true for a normal ListAdapter, but in my case it is more beneficial for me to use a SackOfViewsAdapter so I need to handle that case instead. The whole thing about adapters is a bit misleading here. I'm really looking for a way to manage animation lifecycle when those animators are potentially nested deep within the view hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Note: Thanks to [pskink's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649340/managing-animator-lifecycle-from-within-custom-view-in-custom-list-adapter#comment62780283_37649340) for showing the way.

It looks like `View#onWindowVisibilityChanged` and `View#onDetachedFromWindow` are the best way to go here. In the former, pause/resume the animator (according to if visibility is `View#VISIBLE` or not). In the latter, cancel the animator.

Maybe also start the animator in `View#onAttachedToWindow` depending on your use case.

I won't mark this as accepted yet, in case anyone has a better solution.

Comment: Problem w/ on attach / detach is that the animator will keep running while your app is paused, in the background. That isn't catastrophic, but it is consuming CPU resources for no reason... and if enough apps did this it could be noticeable to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onVisibilityAggregated(boolean isVisible) {
    super.onVisibilityAggregated(isVisible);
    if (isVisible) {} //Animator.start() 
    else {} //Animator.cancel()
```